# Why is my iPhone calendar stuck in the year 2562BE?

Tags: calendar

And how do I change it, to the current year, 2019?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2708919

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - rather than just a link, that could be an answer.